# Reduction of Order to solve, but can't get right answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

Given the equation y'' + 2y' + y = 0  and the solution  y1 = ${xe}^{-x}$. Solve for a second solution $y_2$.

I've solved it twice and get $y_2 = {xe}^{-x}(-{x}^{-1}+c)$ , but that's not being counted as correct. I distributed the ${xe}^{-x}$ in my actual answer.
Can someone please walk me through how to get the solution?

I solved once using $y_2 = y_1(x)\int\frac{e^{-\int P(x) dx}}{y_1^2}$
and again using $y_2 = y_1(x)u(x)$.

Comment: In what ways did you solve it?

Comment: It looks correct, it is only not completely simplified. Note that you can remove multiples of $y_1$ without changing the independence of the second basis solution.

Comment: Edited for more context

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y_2 = c(x) x e^{-x}$. After substitution we arrive at

$$
(2c'(x)-x c''(x))e^{-x}=0
$$

and solving the ode $2c'(x)-x c''(x)=0$ we have

$$
c(x) = c_1+\frac{c_2}{x}
$$

note that $y_2 = c_1x e^{-x}+c_2 e^{-x}$ covers the solutions (two independent constants) so $y_2 = e^{-x}$